# R: Horizontally "collapsing" columns of data frame

Tags: r

I'm new to R and have what is probably a very basic question, but I'm not exactly sure what to call this operation so I've just called it "collapsing." I have a data frame with many columns as follows:

```
x <- data.frame(matrix(0, 10, 10))
x[1, 1:5] <- 1
x[3,6:10] <- 2
x[5,6:10] <- 3
x[6,6:10] <- 4
x[8, 1:5] <- 5
```

... and so on for n rows. So the first 10 look like this:

```
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1   1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0   0
2   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
3   0  0  0  0  0  2  2  2  2   2
4   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
5   0  0  0  0  0  3  3  3  3   3
6   0  0  0  0  0  4  4  4  4   4
7   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
8   5  5  5  5  5  0  0  0  0   0
9   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
```

I'd like to shift the columns `X6:X11` horizontally, so that I have a data frame as follows:

```
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1   1  1  1  1  1
2   0  0  0  0  0 
3   2  2  2  2  2
4   0  0  0  0  0
5   3  3  3  3  3
6   4  4  4  4  4
7   0  0  0  0  0
8   5  5  5  5  5
9   0  0  0  0  0
10  0  0  0  0  0
```

.. but am stuck on how to go about doing this efficiently. Any help for an R novice with this is very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If you continue to treat it as a matrix: `x[,1:5] + x[,6:10]` will give you what you want.

Comment: Thanks, this does the trick! If I want to stay in the data frame, is there an elegant solution (using, e.g., d/plyr or some other package/methods that it would be worth my time to learn)?

Comment: @Percival Frank's answer will still be a data frame. Check `class(x[,1:5] + x[,6:10])`

Answer (score 2):

If that's all you want to do, continue to treat `x` the way you would treat a matrix. You'll get the result you want with:

```
x[,1:5] + x[,6:10]
```

as a `data.frame`.